# Erro ao retornar objeto em array - Javascript

Tags: javascript

Olá, estou com um erro ao retornar objeto em array, objeto não retorna.

```
    let myArray = [{
        "name": [{
            id: 0,
            name: "Jhon"
        }, {
            id: 1,
            name: "Sara"
        }]
    }],


    objIndex = myArray.findIndex((obj => obj.id == 1));

    console.log(myArray[objIndex])
```

Comment: E qual é o erro?

Comment: @JéfBueno Alterei o post, objeto não retorna.

Comment: Em vez de `findIndex`, pode simplesmente fazer `result = myArray[0].name.find(obj => obj.id == 1)` e `result` será o objeto que vc procura (`findIndex` só faz sentido se vc quer saber o índice, mas se quer somente o objeto, usar `find` é mais "direto ao ponto"). Outro ponto é rever essa estrutura, precisa mesmo que seja um array com um único elemento, que por usa vez é um objeto, que contém outro array com outros objetos? A estrutura indicada na resposta abaixo (apenas um array que contém os objetos, sem precisar do "name") é mais simples

Comment: @hkotsubo myArray[0].name, ta ai a resposta hahahaha, valeuuu!!

Answer (score 0):

O problema é bem claro, não existe `id` nos itens de `myArray`. É fácil ver isso apenas fazendo um `log` no primeiro (e único item do array).

```js
let myArray = [{
  "name": [{
    id: 0,
    name: "Jhon"
  }, {
    id: 1,
    name: "Sara"
  }]
}];


console.log(myArray[0]);
```

É mais fácil ver o problema lendo o código em partes.

```js
let myArray = 
[ 
  // ^ Inicia um array
  { 
    // ^ Inicia um objeto
    "name": 
      // ^ Propriedade "name" do objeto 
    [ 
      // ^ Inicia um array (name então é um array)
      { 
        // ^ Inicia um objeto (name é um array de objetos)
        id: 0, 
        name: "Jhon"
        // ^ Propriedades do objeto
      }, { 
        // ^ Outro objeto dentro do array (que está em name)
        id: 1,
        name: "Sara"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Aparentemente você apenas digitou de forma errada a inicialização dos objetos. Neste caso, é só corrigir isso.

```js
let myArray = [{
  id: 0,
  name: "Jhon"
}, {
  id: 1,
  name: "Sara"
}]
 
const objIndex = myArray.findIndex((obj => obj.id == 1));
console.log(myArray[objIndex])
```

Comment: No caso precisaria acessar o name primeiro, dessa forma consegui rodar já.

Comment: @Josimara Não entendi seu comentário

Comment: Você não deveria ter modificado o myArray, e sim usado o meu.

Comment: @Josimara Você deveria ter especificado isso na pergunta...